# Json sample for updating the server

Tags: json, object

I am new to programming with json and want to develop a page where I want to send the details of an object from client side to be saved in the server.

Can you give me a sample code of how to do this?

Any help is highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a framework called DWR (Direct Web Remoting) at www.directwebremoting.com

USing this framework you can call Java class methods from Javascript function and vice versa without knowing or writing any ajax related codes. This automatically converts java objects to json and vice versa.

For e.g

My Java class is like below

```
    public class HelloWorld
    {
       public String sayHelloToPerson(Person p)
       {
         return "Hello "+ p.getName();
       }
    }

     class Person{

     private String name;
     private int age;

     ..
      // getters and  setters goes here...
     ..

     }
```

My Javascript function in my jsp will be like this.

```
    function invokeHello()
    {
        var person = new Object();
            person["name"]="John";
            person["age"] = 21;

        HelloWorld.sayHelloToPerson(person,function(dataReturned)
            { 
                 alert(dataReturned);
            }
        );
    }
```

Try this especially if you dont want to write complex ajax calls and xml parsing codes. Keep it simple.

Comment: and what if the OP does not use java on his server ?

Comment: Actually I want to use php code with json...my server files are all in php